# What is the best control should be used for disabling range of dates and times, so user cannot selects them?

Tags: asp.net, calendar, telerik

I am implementing a business requirement for boats booking, each booking is a period (from datetime : to datetime).
So, I'm looking for a control to implement the following functions:

Disable booked periods so user be aware of booked periods, hence user cannot selects them.

**e.g.** We have the following booked periods

```
BoatName  From                 To                   
Boat 1    01-01-2011 10:00 AM  01-01-2011 12:00 AM  
Boat 1    02-01-2011 09:00 AM  04-01-2011 09:00 AM
```

Based on above booking details, **all dates and times should be available except the following**

**01-01-2011** as a day should be available but times from 10:00 AM to 12:00 shouldn't be available.
**02-01-2011** as a day should be available but times from 09:00 AM to 11:59 PM shouldn't be available.
**03-01-2011** the whole day and time shouldn't be available because the whole days is booked.
**04-01-2011** as a day should be available, but times from 12:00 AM to 09:00 AM shouln't be available.

So, is there a control that can implement that functionality?
Or, if I'm going to use ASP.NET Calendar Control or Telerik Calendar Control, how to implement such functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you can do that with the telerik calendar using coding as in these demos:
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/carrental/default.aspx
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/calendar/examples/design/sunny/defaultcs.aspx

You may also take a peek at other live demos for picker validation they have or projects in their code library.

Comment: Telerik Calendar can do this, if you take in consideration SpecialDays collection.